# gulp "scss" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: css, gulp, npm, scss

Ребята, спасайте!
Суть в том, что этот же проект работает отлично на одном компе, а когда пытаюсь запустить его на другом - не отрабатывает только таску, которая компилирует scss в css. И только на этом компе! Все остальное работает по отдельности отлично.

ошибок нет
пути все правильные
ничего не менялось, но на одном компе пашет, а на другом - нет.

ай нид хелп)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: удали node_modules, очисть кэш npm и установи всё снова.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!

Comment: я ввожу команду gulp scss - она не работает (повторюсь - только на одном компе), остальные команды выполняются

Comment: введи gulp-sass

Comment: `gulp scss` это запуск таски, а `gulp-sass` - наименование пакета

Comment: я надеюсь у ТС Linux?

Comment: @norbornen, все равно не работает(

Comment: @misdeed, нет. винда 10. но опять таки. на другом компе с виндой все то же самое - абсолютно. не могу понять где проблема

Comment: @norbornen я в курсе) все пакеты установлены. и все работают, кроме одного - который компилирует scss to css

Comment: О, если винда, тогда я не знаю. Перестал ей пользоваться, когда только вышла 7. Так что, помочь не могу.

Comment: @misdeed, угу. спасибо! жаль

Comment: @JKaminsky О, я придумал походу! Надо переустановить вендовс!

Comment: @misdeed, хах) минутка сарказма? С виндой все ок

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен!
Оказалось, еще вчера пакет gulp-scss работал отлично, а сегодня уже считается устаревшим, поэтому лучше использовать gulp-sass.

Теперь все работает)